# Downloading a text file into a String fails while debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, swift-playground

I have the following code:

```
    if let fileURL = URL(string: dataFileURL) {
        do {
            let rawContent = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return rawContent
        } catch {
            print("Error loading remote file")
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid string URL")
        return nil
    }
```

I'm trying to download the content of a CSV file into a String. The file is on my machine and is accessible through http://localhost/....

The above code runs fine in a playground but fails while debugging with the following error:

```
NSError domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 256
```

The code I'm using appears in many sample code as perfectly ok however googling the error reveals plenty of folks experiencing it but without a cleat solution.

Any clue as to why the different behaviour and what the solution might be?

thank you.

Comment: Are you downloading it in Base64 format. If yes it might be issue of Url encoding.

Comment: I have tried different .utf8 with no difference. The only explanation I have for why it is not failing is that iOS is enforcing some kind of restriction to non standard hostname. since localhost does not have a domain this might be triggering the error. just a guess.

Comment: Might be you can host your site with domain name on Azure its free if you want to use it to test and will not take more than 10 minutes, if you do not have any other option.

Comment: Using `String(contentsOf:)` is a really bad way of loading a remote file. Use `URLSession`.

Comment: Are you debugging in the simulator or a real iOS device? Keep in mind that "localhost" means "the device the app is running on". So if your are debugging on a real iOS device, "localhost" is the iOS device and that is unlikely what you want.

Comment: I was debugging in the simulator. I tried both suggestions (storing the file on a server and using `URLSession`. both worked! I still don't get why the simulator freaks out about the `localhost`. thanks guys!!